# How do I install Keras version 0.1.0 with Theano as the backend on Ubuntu (in 2019)?

Tags: python, keras, theano

I tried with:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ Keras==0.1.0
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting Keras==0.1.0
  Using cached https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/08/7f1c6bfaa86e69ccadadc552d6309f1685d779a93047d0a7c317b26a321e/Keras-0.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-O0DpNQ/Keras/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        long_description = open('README.md').read(),
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'

   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-O0DpNQ/Keras/
```

Comment: Try using `conda`, it will be way simpler. Start by installing [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Comment: "Kereas version 0.1.0" is not  in the installation list.                                                                I got this when tried with conda install->PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Answer (score -1):

Edit the setup.py and remove the line:-
long_description = open('README.md').read(),